# once i click on an image, bind and display the image with all other data on another page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to do something like all the e-commerce sites using now a days. once you click on an image,it should show the bigger image in another page along with all the details like price,size,specification etc. can anyone tell me how to do that in asp.net.

Comment: Normally some e-commerce sites keep Thump image, Small,Medium and Large image to do so.